# Retrieve time from MySQL as HH:MM format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time

I used `DATETIME` datatype to store date and time in my Database.  It saved date as

```
YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (2012-11-06 10:45:48)
```

I can retrieve the time from database as `HH:MM:SS` format but I want to retrieve it in `HH:MM` format.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) Function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%H:%i') FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 6):

You will want to use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select date_format(yourDateColumn, '%h:%i') yourTime
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fff9/2)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,  '%H:%i' ) AS time_column
```