# Why shows Mysql time output value as hhmmss instead of hh:mm:ss?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following query which works perfectly except for column 'Time'. My output is coming as `hhmmss`, but I want `hh:mm:ss`

```
select Agent_ID, date(Start_Time),
       SUM(CASE WHEN Break_Reason = 'teabreak' THEN login.Time ELSE NULL END) TeaBreak
from login 
where Agent_ID = '3331'
  and date(start_time) = '2016-04-02';
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Don't you need a group by?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve time from MySQL as HH:MM format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250531/retrieve-time-from-mysql-as-hhmm-format)

Comment: That's totally different question...here I am not asking to change HH:MM:SS to HH:MM...I am asking to change HHMMSS to HH:MM:SS

Comment: @jarlh please help as an with what do i have to group by

Comment: It's not easy to understand what combination of agent/start/teatime you want. Try to add `GROUP BY Agent_ID, date(Start_Time)` at the end, and see shat happens.

Comment: @jarlh it's coming as same...my output comes as:

Agent_ID  date(Start_Time) TeaBreak
3331  2016-04-02      2037

Only I want my TeaBreak to show as 00:20:37 instead of 2037

Comment: My comment wasn't regarding date format, it was an attempt correcting your invalid group by.

Comment: @jarlh oh understood.....can you help me with output if possible

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at date_format(date, format):

```
select Agent_ID, date_format(date(Start_Time),'%H:%i:%S'),
   SUM(CASE WHEN Break_Reason = 'teabreak' THEN login.Time ELSE NULL END) TeaBreak
from login 
where Agent_ID = '3331'
and date(start_time) = '2016-04-02';
```

For more info, take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp